# ¿Por qué no funciona mi ajax de load()?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mysqli

llevo un rato intentando(digamos, unos días intentando) que funcione, pero no funciona y no da error, no tengo ni la más mínima idea de por qué no funciona el código, aparentemente, todo está bien escrito y el código php es correcto porque  antes lo tengo también dentro del div y funciona todo correctamente, el problema es como de AJAX

AJAX:

```
 <script      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    var id = <?php echo $_GET["title"];?>
      setInterval(function() {
        $("#lista").load("includes/loader.php" {
     id:id
        });
    }, 500);
 </script>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php 
$id = $_POST["id"];
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "userlist12");

  $consulta2="SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE titulo  = '".$id."' ORDER BY id DESC";
  $resultado2 = mysqli_query($db, $consulta2);
  if($resultado2){
      while($row2= $resultado2->fetch_array()){
$sq = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$row2['usuario']}'";
   $ru = mysqli_query($db, $sq);
    $ro = mysqli_fetch_array($ru);
      $photou = $ro['photo'];
          echo "

           <div style='height: 7%;'></div>

          <div id='container'>

           <a href='profile.php?user={$row2['usuario']}'><img id='ph' src='images/users/$photou'>
          <div> {$row2['usuario']} </a> <eti>{$row2['mensaje']}</eti>



        </div></div>";
      }
  }

 ?>
```

Comment: Puedes poner la ruta a la que debe llegar, quiza te falte una `/` al inicio de la ruta

Comment: no funciona con eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te recomiendo que des una mirada en la documentación del load
https://api.jquery.com/load/

Actualiza tu JS a este

`setInterval(
  () => $("#lista").load("includes/loader.php", () => { id:id }), 
  5000
);`

Ten en cuenta que este código se ejecutará cada 5 segundos en tu página.
Si lo que quieres es ejecutarlo una vez luego de que tu sitio se cargue debes agregar lo siguiente:

`window.load = $("#lista").load("includes/loader.php", () => { id:id });`

Saludos!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me sirvió lo primero :)

Answer (score 1):

En principio te falta una `,` después de la URL, debería ser así

```
$("#lista").load("includes/loader.php", {
     id:id
});
```

Comment: Aun así sigue sin funcionar

Comment: llega el request al php?

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta, es que no sé mucho de AJAX ni Javascript.

Comment: Lo que te pregunta Adrian es si la pestaña Network o Console te muestran algun error, para ello puedes usar las Dev Tools de tu navegador o con F12

Comment: chat.php:11 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier pero ese script no tiene nada que ver  con este, son dos muy distintos, además ese script me funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que ser esto solucione tu problema:

```
$("#lista").load("includes/loader.php",() => {
 id:id
});
```

Comment: No, sigue sin hacer nada.